# Python 3.6 + tkinter: Stop while loop with Button

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop

at the moment I am struggling with stopping a while loop with a button in Python 3.6 with tkinter that I run on Windows 10.
I did quite some reading and tried to put everything in the code (calling the after method on root; giving the after method an int for the time; calling a function reference, rather than a function), but still I can't get my head around it yet.
The code appended is somewhat lengthy due to the GUI-lines, the troublesome part is marked with headline:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# GUI for Servotester with Arduino

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
from time import time

# Servo Handler Object
class ServoLine:                 
    def __init__(self, ServoNumber, frame_body, COMPort, master):
        ### Setting up the Technical Components
        # GUI Basic Components
        self.master = master
        self.frame_body = frame_body
        self.COMPort = COMPort
        # Technical Components
        self.PingPongExec = False   # Toggle to run Ping Pong Command               
        self.PingPongDirect = False # Direction of Ping Pong Servo Travel
        self.SleepTime = 1000       # Time to next command
        self.Min = 1020
        self.Max = 1980
        # GUI Components
        self.Place = ServoNumber
        self.Mode = StringVar()
        self.ServoPos = ttk.Entry(self.frame_body, width=15)
        self.ServoPos.insert(0, '1500')  
        self.ServoMin = ttk.Entry(self.frame_body, width=15)
        self.ServoMin.insert(0, '1020') 
        self.ServoMax = ttk.Entry(self.frame_body, width=15)
        self.ServoMax.insert(0, '1980') 
        self.PingPongTime = ttk.Entry(self.frame_body, width=15)
        self.PingPongTime.insert(0, '1000') 
        self.ComboMode = ttk.Combobox(self.frame_body, textvariable=self.Mode, values=('Go Straight', 'Ping Pong'), width=10)
        self.Mode.set('Go Straight')
        self.Start = ttk.Button(self.frame_body, text='Start', command=self.StartButton)
        self.Stop = ttk.Button(self.frame_body, text='Stop', command=self.StopButton)
        # Now build the GUI
        ttk.Label(self.frame_body, text='{}'.format(ServoNumber)).grid(row=ServoNumber, column=0, sticky='w', padx=5)   
        self.ServoPos.grid(row=ServoNumber, column=1, sticky='w', padx=5)
        self.ServoMin.grid(row=ServoNumber, column=2, sticky='w', padx=5)
        self.ServoMax.grid(row=ServoNumber, column=3, sticky='w', padx=5)
        self.PingPongTime.grid(row=ServoNumber, column=4, sticky='w', padx=5)
        self.ComboMode.grid(row=ServoNumber, column=5, padx=5)
        self.Start.grid(row=ServoNumber, column=6)
        self.Stop.grid(row=ServoNumber, column=7)

    ###### TROUBLESOME PART START ######
    def StartButton(self):
        # GOING STRAIGHT Execution
        if self.Mode.get() == 'Go Straight':
            print('Servo {} is going straight to Position {}'.format(self.Place, self.ServoPos.get()))
            print('The COMPort is: {}'.format(self.COMPort))
        # PING PONG Execution
        else:
            self.PingPongExec = True
            self.SleepTime = int(self.PingPongTime.get())    # Most likely not the most elegant, but I dont want to call .get() in while loop...
            self.Min = self.ServoMin.get()
            self.Max = self.ServoMax.get()
            # Looping
            while self.PingPongExec: self.RunPingPong()

    def RunPingPong(self):
        if self.PingPongDirect:     # self.PingPongDirect is either True or False
            print('Servo {} is going up to Position {}'.format(self.Place, self.Max))
            self.PingPongDirect = False
            self.master.after(self.SleepTime, self.RunPingPong)
            print(time())
        else:
            print('Servo {} is going down to Position {}'.format(self.Place, self.Min))
            self.PingPongDirect = True
            self.master.after(self.SleepTime, self.RunPingPong)
            print(time())

    def StopButton(self):
        self.PingPongExec = False
        print('Setting PingPongExec to 0')
    ###### TROUBLESOME PART END ######


class ServoGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.resizable('false', 'false')
        self.master.title('nanoServo-Driver')

        # COM-Port Handling and Auto-Connecting
        self.COMPortList = list()
        self.COMPort = 'COM1'
        self.COMPortsList = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports()) # Get names of all COMPorts

        # Try except block to be able to test programm without a Arduino attached
        try:
            for p in self.COMPortsList:
                if "CH340" in p[1]: # Looking for a Arduino Clone
                    self.COMPort = p[0]
                    print(self.COMPort)
                    break        
                else:
                    pass
            self.Ser = serial.Serial(self.COMPort, 57600)
            self.Ser.write(2000)
        except: print('Connection setup failed!')

        ### Frame with choice of COM-Port
        frame_header=ttk.Frame(self.master)
        frame_header.pack(anchor='w')
        message = 'Arduino found on {}. '.format(self.COMPort)
        ttk.Label(frame_header, text=message).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
        ttk.Button(frame_header, text='Disconnect', command=self.Disconnect).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='w')
        # Giving connection status to the user


        ### Frame with Servo configuration
        # Table Header
        frame_body=ttk.Frame(self.master)
        frame_body.pack(anchor='w')
        ttk.Label(frame_body, text='Servo').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=10)  # Column 'Servo'
        ttk.Label(frame_body, text='Servoposition [mu_s]'). grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)       # Column 'Servoposition'
        ttk.Label(frame_body, text='Lower Position [mu_s]').grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5)       # Column 'Lower Position'
        ttk.Label(frame_body, text='Upper Position [mu_s]').grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5)       # Column 'Lower Position'
        ttk.Label(frame_body, text='Ping Pong Time [ms]').grid(row=0, column=4, padx=5)         # Column 'Time Ping Pong'
        ttk.Label(frame_body, text='Mode').grid(row=0, column=5, padx=5, sticky='w')            # Column 'Lower Position'
        # Calling the Objects for the Servos. Per Servo one line. 
        self.Servo1 = ServoLine(1, frame_body, self.COMPort, self.master)     

    # Disconnect Method
    def Disconnect(self):
        self.Ser.close()


### MAIN-Function       
def main():            
    root = Tk()
    Servo = ServoGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

I want to exit the while-loop in the StartButton-method by running the StopButton-method by clicking the Stop-Button. The StopButton-method will set the property self.PingPongExec to FALSE, but due to the loop, it won't let me click the stop-Button.

Sorry for the basic question, but I got a knot im my head.

Kind regards,

Sebastian

Comment: use `tkiner.after(milliseconds, function_name)` instead of `while` to run `RunPingPong` and then it will not stop `mainloop()` which does all job in tkinter - it gets mouse/key events, sends events to widgets, update widgets, redraws widgets, executes functions assigned to buttons, executes functions assigned by after(), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *not* run a loop in an event handler method or function like `StartButton`!

Event handlers are being called from the mainloop when certain events occur. While your event handler is running, no further event processing can occur.

In the event handler `StartButton`, just use the `after` method to schedule `RunPingPong`.

Comment: Thanks for that advice! Looks like I hadn't understood a basic thing. Now the method StartButton just calls the method RunPingPong once who calls itself with root.after() (or in my case root = master).

Comment: You're welcome. :-) You were mostly there already. It's one of the fundamental properties of GUI tooltkits that your code is basically a guest in the main event loop. So you have to chop up long running tasks into small pieces.